# matplotlib.fill_between not working with mdates

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I want to create a plot like this:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTyo5.png)

but in the x_axis I want to display the date. I have an array of datetime dates that I generate by cycling through different values for `path_time:`

```
           times.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(path_time,"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))
```

I can easily plot the scatter points like this:

```
for i in range(1,np.size(times)):

   plt.scatter(times[i],y[i],color='red')
```

To plot the errors, I generate the arrays y1 and y2 from the standard deviation of the data y and want to fill the area in between.

```
plt.fill_between(times,y1,y2,where=y>0.4,alpha=0.4,color='blue')
```

This works fine if the x axis is defined by integer vales but not if it's defined as dates which raises the error:

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

any advice how to solve this problem or work around it so that the error bar is plotted to the corresponding scatter point while still having the date on the x axis?

Comment: Use x-y data list elements index as axis index(so value not a position)

Comment: thanks that works for a workaround. Meanwhile I found the actual error/solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mdates does work with fill_between. The problem was that after some handling of the dates, I was faced with an object. Then it doesn't work.

If the input for the x values is a list of dates, it works fine.